# Voice communication betwen devices example?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-intent

I want to make an android app that connects with other devices and make voice communication , where one can speak while others listen . Is there a way to do it without internet connection or via bluetooth or wifi direct. Thanks for sharing if someone has some experience about this kind of app.

Success !

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow .Please take the time to read to see  [Ask]

Answer (score -1):

You can do it without internet connection.

I have already done this with wifi-direct and it works. You need to establish a wifi-direct connection then create socket on devices.
You can use AudioRecorder to acquire the voice and send it with an OutputStream link to the socket and you can receive the data in the other device with an Inputstream and interpret it with an AudioTrack.